# MongoDB Administration through command line scripts

Tags: mongodb

in mysql I can administer my database (the primary goal is to a have an automated build of the database by sequentially applying changes to it with scripts) by running commands like this:

```
mysql -u root my_database < script_1.sql
mysql -u root my_database < script_2.sql
```

Where script_1.sql looks like this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_database;
CRATE DATABASE my_database;
```

And script_2.sql something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ...
```

Ok, I want to to the same for mongo, but instead of running SQL commands I would like to run mongo db commands.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in mongo, objects are created  on the fly (when you insert the first object in the first collection of a database), so maybe you don't need to create database and collection.

Then you can use 2 different tools to populate your databases with objects : mongoimport and mongo

```
mongo -d myDatabase --eval  "db.aCollection.insert({_id : ..,....,....})"
```

or

```
mongo -d myDatabase --eval bob.js
```

can execute any javascript you want. This is done with a lock on the db, so do not use this on an instance that is used for requests.

The second method is to use `mongoimport` as said on other response. This is easier if you have a list of objects and no other type of commands. Note that objects are upserted (not inserted) so duplicates should not fail.

Comment: It seems that now the `-d` flag is not needed. You can just use `mongo myDatabase --eval ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [import](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3aImportfileformat) tool and batch files good fit for your needs.

> For example, if you imported a file that looks like this:
>
> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e5bb37258200ed9aabc5d65" }, "name" : "Bob",
>   "age" : 28, "address" : "123 fake street" }
>
> by running
>
> mongoimport -d test -c foo importfile.json

To drop database you can stop mongodb (also via batch file), remove database files,and start database again.